# NumPy linear equations

Tags: python, numpy

I was wondering to check for an algorithm that would solve set of three linear equations in two variables which change in every equation adjacently for example

- a + b = 0
- a + c = 0
- b + c = 1

I am open to all suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Use the np.linalg.solve library:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,1,0], [1,0,1], [0,1,1]])
b = np.array([0,0,1])
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
```

Comment: Sir I need an algorithm to convert these three linear equations into array form. I know the NumPy method but firstly I would need to get them in array form

Comment: You mean something like a = np.ones(3) - np.identity(3) ?

Comment: It doesn't bother me if you use numpy or simple python algorithm but I will need all the coefficients in simple array form in order to use np.linalg

Answer (score 0):

alternative to the answer

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]])
B = np.array([0, 0, 1])
X = np.linalg.inv(A).dot(B)

print(X)
```

Comment: Mam I need an algorithm to convert these three linear equations into array form. I know the NumPy method but firstly I would need to get them in array form